# Запятая перед «каково это». Функции слова «наконец»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, сложное-предложение

*Я смогу, **наконец**, почувствовать **каково это**, сразу понимать себя, а не бесконечно думать, что именно я чувствую.*

*Я **наконец** смогу в полной мере ощутить эмоции, которые я так хотела понять, а не испытывать те жалкие крохи, что мне доступны.*

Верно ли, что запятая перед "каково это" не нужна?
И является ли "наконец" в первом и втором предложениях вводным словом?

Comment: Хотелось бы, чтобы вы разбили вопрос на два отдельных. Это совершенно разные случаи.

Answer (score 2):

Неверно, что запятая не нужна. С союзного слова "каково" начинается придаточное.

**[КАКОВ, КАКОВА, КАКОВО, *союзн. сл.*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2&all=x)**

> Употр. для присоединения изъяснительных и определительных придаточных
>   предложений. *Принимай меня, каков я есть. Теперь я понимаю, каково
>   ему было жить одному.*

---

Если Вы - автор этих двух предложений, то запятые могут обрамлять "наконец", а могут и отдыхать.

*Я смогу, наконец, почувствовать, каково это — сразу понимать себя, а не
бесконечно думать, что именно я чувствую.*

Запятые тут означают, что некие изменившие Ваше мироощущение обстоятельства триумфально завершаются новым пониманием себя. (А до этого они, неведомые нам обстоятельства, изменили ещё что-то.)  Оценка факта с точки зрения говорящего.

**[НАКОНЕЦ, *вводное слово*](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:13liFPtEeNAJ:new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum%3Flayout%3Ditem%26id%3D58_436%20&cd=3&hl=ru&ct=clnk&gl=ru)**

> Указывает на то, что слово (выражение), которое следует далее,
>   заключает сказанное ранее или является последним; также выражает
>   недовольство, нетерпение, досаду.
>
> *Один засмеялся, за ним второй, десятый, сотый и, наконец, последний.* Ф. Кривин, Хвост павлина. *Генеле доставала из заветной сумки новые
>   деньги, и царская невеста, сохраняя неестественное положение вниз
>   головой, переходила в руки Генеле, которая заворачивала ее во многие
>   газеты, потом в чистую белую тряпку, потом в сетку и, наконец, в
>   хозяйственную сумку.* Л. Улицкая, Генеле-сумочница. *Сядьте у камина,
>   перечтите что-нибудь легкое, выпейте, наконец, вина.* В. Пелевин,
>   Хрустальный мир. *Да оставь ты меня, наконец!*
>
> **! Не смешивать** с употреблением в роли члена предложения (в знач. «в
>   конечном итоге, после всего, напоследок, под конец, в результате
>   всего»).

Второе предложение:

*Я наконец смогу в полной мере ощутить эмоции, которые я так хотела понять, а не испытывать те жалкие крохи, что мне доступны, —*

как раз тот случай, когда просят ***не смешивать с вводным*** и, стало быть, не обособлять.

Comment: Нет, не согласен. Никаких однозначных аргументов в пользу обособления или не обособления "наконец" в данных предложениях нет. Это ваши предположения. В частности, второе предложение тоже может содержать выражение, "которое следует далее, заключает сказанное ранее или является последним", если перед ним стояло предложение с иными доводами.

Comment: Мой ответ начинается словами: "Если Вы - автор этих двух предложений, то запятые могут обрамлять "наконец", а могут и отдыхать". То есть как угодно ощущать собственную интонацию автору.

Comment: Я говорил не про эти вполне справедливые слова, а про финальный совет не обособлять "наконец" во втором предложении. Оно вполне может обособляться, если, например, перед ним стояли фразы с "во-первых" и "во-вторых".

Answer (score 1):

Со словом "наконец" ситуация непростая. Правило состоит в том, что "наконец" является вводным словом, если не имеет временного (иногда расширяют: "пространственно-временного") значения. То есть если его можно заменить синонимами "в итоге", "в результате", "после всего" - это не вводное:

> Мы строили, строили и наконец построили! (Чебурашка)

Если же оно указывает связь мыслей, то это вводное:

> Надо себе, наконец, цену знать. (Тургенев)

Ваши случаи без контекста разобрать нельзя.

Проблема в том, что в значительном числе случаев это сложно понять без точного знания того, что имеет в виду автор:

> Я смогу наконец почувствовать себя хорошо = Я смогу после всех этих процедур почувствовать себя хорошо.
>
> Я смогу, наконец, почувствовать себя хорошо = Я смогу, помимо прочих преимуществ,  почувствовать себя хорошо.